# Architecture for solution to Industrial IoT

Tags: machine-learning, blockchains

I am trying to build an IoT solution for connecting industrial machinery(250 global divisions, with each division having about a dozen machines). I plan to capture and collect critical data regarding machine run time, down time, temperature etc. to be able to do analysis and use machine learning to provide maintenance information for this machines. I have worked on a small version of IoT solution, and I am quite familiar with Raspberry Pi, Azure IoTHub etc, but how do I start here? I have read many blogs that talks about using Blockchain to connect machinery to IoT, but could not find anything as to "how" exactly that can be done.

What I am looking for here is not the exact solution, but some information/references to start with. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I agree this is too broad. There is plenty of material to read (although mostly focused on platform solutions). I think this is also too 'emerging technology' for there to be much in the way of 'standard texts'.

Comment: would it help if I provide more details?

Comment: You're asking 'teach me the system architecture'. That will always be too broad, especially when the choices are kind of on a par. You might as well ask 'which desktop OS should each of my offices use'. Do ignore anyone who uses the blockchain buzzword as part of the sales pitch (even if it can be a sensible technical detail in an overall solution). We can't teach you how to design this solution, but we can possibly explain how a distributed ledger might have value in addressing a specific problem in your network design. One narrow issue per question will help.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane okay. would be able to suggest me the approach I should use to connect these division's machinery to cloud? If we talk about blockchain, are there any starters as to how to begin? Also, as I mentioned in OP, I understand that all of this is still in the emerging phase, and I'm not looking for a complete solution, just some helpful references.